# Parallel LED connection break

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, switches

I have 10 parallel connected LEDs all the same color and one single pole double throw (SPDT) switch. I want to configure them in such a way that when common of SPDT connects to NC connection all LEDS will glow simultaneously. But when common connects to NO connection I want only 5 of them to glow.

Comment: [LEDs in parallel](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=Leds+in+parallel)

Comment: are you saying that you want 5 LEDs to be controlled by a switch, and 5 LEDs to be continuously on? ... that reduces to `5 LEDs powered through a switch` ... what is preventing you from inserting a switch into the circuit?

Answer (score 0):

You can take out ground from 2 points one from the end of the 10 leds and one form the middle i.e 5 leds and connect them respectively to the NC and NO pins of the switch while the middle pin of the switch will be connected to the ground of the power supply and the leds will have a constant connection to the +ve of the power supply. You can also make the connections vice-versa

Comment: the LEDs are all wired in parallel though...